# Malformed JSON at Retrift API?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm new in Android development. This is my MainActivity.java. I already set the lenient and still receiving error `D/onFailure: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`

API returns: Its either `Success` or Validation like `Error: FirstName is invalid.`

```
private void saveUser() {
    showpDialog();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    User user = new User();

    user.setFirstName(editName.getText().toString());

    Call<User> call = service.saveUser(user.getFirstName());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response) {
            hidepDialog();
            Log.d("onResponse", "" + response.code() +
                    "  response body "  + response.body() +
                    " responseError " + response.errorBody() + " responseMessage " +
                    response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            hidepDialog();
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Ive been searching and all of them says i need to setLenient to true, but I already did that. Any idea?

Comment: Would you share your JSON please?

Comment: Are you getting the `response.body()` on success?
What is your exact response on success? `{success}`?
Because my opinion for this depends on it

Comment: I'm using PHP as my API, and the return is just an echo of `Success` or `Validation`

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26115500/5612708) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `Success` or `Validation` is not a valid JSON. I think that's why it's malformed. JSON is kind like this:

```
{ "status": "success" }
```

So, you should not parse it as JSON, but just read at as a raw string instead. Or, it's better to make your response from server become a valid JSON like above.

More more better to make it RESTful, that's read status from HTTP response status instead of response body, either it is `200 OK` or other status code. But it's out of question, so for now just use JSON.

Comment: You're right, i just need to edit my response to an valid JSON. Thanks!